# HTML input element - type "reset" not clearing form always

Tags: jquery, html, input, types, reset

I have a simple search interface - a form with few input fields and submit button. In order to clear the text or values from the input fields I have also input element with type "reset".

```
<input name="commit" type="reset" value="Clear">
```

If I click on this input it clears all fields, but not always. If I firstly submit the form, then the "reset" input is not clearing the fields. Is this normal behavior?

Also, I have decided to ensure myself that the fields will be always clear using jQuery and adding function on the input above "click" event:

```
$('input:reset').on('click',function(){

  var form = $(this).closest('form');

  $(form).find('input:text').val('');
  $(form).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);

});
```

That's not working either. It is pretty strange, because if I execute in the console the following line it clears the inputs successfully:

```
$('input:reset').closest('form').find('input:text').val('');
```

Could anyone suggest what can I try to fix this?